# in browser, how to move from called tab to calling tab?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

in a modern, tabbed browser, if I have a page in one tab that opens a page in another tab

1. how can I move from the second tab to the first tab?
2. how can I move to the first tab when the second tab is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMAIK you can't. This is a security concern. From father tab (which is a [browsing context](http://thoughtresults.com/browsing-context)) you have access to the child tab (which is another browsing context). But not vice versa.

You might test `window.parent.focus()` method, but I got no result.

Comment: you might be right, but I don't see how _going to a tab_ per se is a security risk.  is there any way to name the tab you're in, similar to `target` in href?

Comment: Going to another tab via API means that you have access to it and probably you can gain its control. Imagine that I have a website called `evil.com` and when you visit it, I simply close any other tab opening in your browser. See? That's a trivial example. I suggest you stick to web normal behaviors. None of the giant websites (google, facebook, twitter, etc.) jump or even try to jump from one tab to another. Maybe you have to change your design ;).

Comment: you might be right.  instead of mult-tab, simply replace the current tab contents.  since the bulk is javascript, it should be cached, so the context switch should not be too painful.  on the other hand, it's quite useful for users to have the content split between tabs.